# Set of smooth maps between manifolds is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

If $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$, respectively.

Is set of smooth maps between them a smooth manifold? With which smooth structure?

Comment: What do you think? Suppose it is, what's its dimension?

Comment: Try a really simple example first and see if you can determine what's what. Compact spaces are particularly nice, so try letting $M = N = S^1$. Like Amitai asks, what should its dimension be? We'll need that to construct the charts. Then you'll need to figure out what the appropriate notion of a "neighborhood" of a mapping is, also necessary for constructing the charts. If you can do all that, try to find the homeomorphisms and then prove the compatibility condition on the chart overlaps. And, if that works, try using less-nice spaces to see if the idea breaks down ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite a deep question. A lot of deep answers are given in [this article by Richard Hamilton](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-07-01/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2.pdf), which is one of my all-time favorite math papers.